# How to transform data from rows into matrix on R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, transform

I want to convert a data set into a matrix on R.

For example, my dataset is:

```
"A";"B";"C";"D"     (cell A1 on excel)
1;"yes";"no";0.1    (cell A2)
3;"yes";"yes";0.9   (cell A3)
7;"no";"yes";0.5    (cell A4)
```

I want to get this matrix on R:

```
A     B    C     D
1   yes   no   0.1
3   yes  yes   0.9
7    no  yes   0.5
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Save as a CSV, read it into R using `;` as the delimiter? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: You could even separate the columns in Excel using the text to columns feature and save it as a proper CSV to load into R.

Comment: See `read.csv2` where delimiter is `";"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also read the excel file using `read.csv` function, it will automatically give the output in dataframe as per your excel file structure.